# Hide source error (lines of code) when throwing exception

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I hide line of source throwing an exception in yellow screen of death? For example, consider following screen of potential dangerous request:

[image]

**In above example, source lines are not displayed. Whereas, if it is any custom written code throwing an exception, lines of error are always displayed as following:**

[image]

How can I hide lines of code (similar to first image) when throwing an error?

Comment: thanks guys for being so prompt.. but I'm looking for hiding lines of source code only for one instance in an application where I'm explicitly throwing an error. I'm happy with default settings otherwise of displaying YOSD with all details. In this one instance I'm checking existence of some values in http request and if I find one, I am throwing httprequestvalidation error (kind of imitating "a potential dangerous..error". If my source code displays, it will also show the values I'm checking.

Answer (score 9):

Set the `mode` attribute of the [`customErrors` section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y123fsf7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to `RemoteOnly` in your "web.config" file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

This enables you to see detailed errors when you are browsing the website locally on your server but does not expose detailed errors for remote visitors.

Alternatively, set it to `On` instead of `RemoteOnly` to completely hide detailed errors, no matter whether you are browsing remotely or locally.

Comment: `Alternatively, set it to Off instead of RemoteOnly to completely hide detailed errors,`...thats wrong ....Setting to Off `will` show the details. you should set it to `On`

Comment: Thanks, @RoyiNamir I've changed my typo. Thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 1):

you can configure this in your web config customErrors definition.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 1):

To do this is very simple, just edit your web.config file so that:

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" />
```

Answer (score 0):

as it is clearly telling is Potentially dangerous request, user may sending un-sanitized data like

`<script type="text/javascript"> alert('sdas');</script>` .

and you even check this link [Prevent Script exploits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a2a4yykt%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

1. you can HtmlEncode method, [HTML Encode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz.aspx)
2. you can disable the custome Errors in web config

web config

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"/>
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 0):

add those lines to Web.config

```
<configuration>
    ...

    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="On"
                      defaultRedirect="~/ErrorPages/Oops.aspx" />

        ...
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: From my experience is not a good practice to set the error page as an .aspx page. Think that the error might be from a module or from invalid config file and then Oops.aspx won't get any chance to be displayed.

Comment: @AdrianIftode I gave him the option ( and so MSDN) mode="On" is there. if he needs / doesnt need the default page - he can remove it.

Comment: I'm only saying that is better to have a html page which doesn't go through ASP .Net engine, than an aspx page which is handled by ASP .Net. Just a thought..

Answer (score 0):

If this is live and not on a development machine, it shouldn't appear at all.

You might check `<customErrors>` from `web.config` so you can set to show a nice html page (plain static, not aspx, not handled by ASP .Net) which says that an error happened, etc.

Then [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) is good for logging these errors (including the source lines, will need to see were the errors occurred so you can fix etc).

Also, live websites should not be deployed in *DEBUG* mode, but in *Release* mode. For `Web Site Projects` this can be switched in `config` only, but for `Web Application Projects` you need to compile with the proper settings.

Answer (score 0):

make a fake class  -  create dll

```
public static class yummy
{
    public static FAKER()
    {
       throw new exception();
    }
}
```

goto your currently working project. 
add reference that DLL
go   where you want to throw error . write this.

```
// lines of codes
yummy.Faker();
```

i put it in a some constructor of static class  ie helper12. Then exception seemed like it was coming from  helper12 class